# split column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split the `ji` column in my `df` into two columns using the comma delimiter - would also be good to get rid of the brackets around the `ji` values. I have tried various methods and keep getting errors. I would like to avoid the use of `lambda expression` for now! Any other ideas?

Example

```
      ji           length
0     (75.0, 5.0)  3283.458479
1     (96.0, 5.0)  1431.312901
2     (97.0, 5.0)  1364.592959
3    (247.0, 5.0)  3736.322308
4     (81.0, 7.0)  2655.910005
5     (93.0, 7.0)  1752.293687
6    (242.0, 7.0)   427.844417
7    (248.0, 7.0)  3725.823013
8    (254.0, 7.0)  2318.937332
9    (255.0, 7.0)  2292.673905
10   (242.0, 8.0)   145.811907
11   (254.0, 8.0)  2222.447786
12   (255.0, 8.0)  2196.184360
13   (248.0, 9.0)   441.222866
14   (253.0, 9.0)   853.095032
15   (256.0, 9.0)  2076.942682
16   (91.0, 10.0)  1743.310744
17   (93.0, 10.0)  1256.337420
18  (105.0, 10.0)   523.447658
19  (174.0, 10.0)  1530.617012
20  (176.0, 10.0)  1697.614009
21  (248.0, 10.0)   440.000463
22  (253.0, 10.0)   904.706003
23  (256.0, 10.0)  1991.662604
24  (258.0, 10.0)  1850.995862
25  (172.0, 11.0)  1301.179960
26  (174.0, 11.0)  1436.984094
27  (176.0, 11.0)  1695.954099
28  (179.0, 11.0)  1548.015013
29  (228.0, 11.0)  4640.928585
30  (242.0, 11.0)   169.617203
31  (251.0, 11.0)   784.921333
32  (253.0, 11.0)   983.118859
33  (255.0, 11.0)  1181.474433
34  (256.0, 11.0)  1303.398235
```

You can load the above example using:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = """\
ji:length
(75.0,5.0):3283.458479
(96.0,5.0):1431.312901
(97.0,5.0):1364.592959
(247.0,5.0):3736.322308
(81.0,7.0):2655.910005
(93.0,7.0):1752.293687
(242.0,7.0):427.844417
(248.0,7.0):3725.823013
(254.0,7.0):2318.937332
(255.0,7.0):2292.673905
(242.0,8.0):145.811907
(254.0,8.0):2222.447786
(255.0,8.0):2196.184360
(248.0,9.0):441.222866
(253.0,9.0):853.095032
(256.0,9.0):2076.942682
(91.0,10.0):1743.310744
(93.0,10.0):1256.337420
(105.0,10.0):523.447658
(174.0,10.0):1530.617012
(176.0,10.0):1697.614009
(248.0,10.0):440.000463
(253.0,10.0):904.706003
(256.0,10.0):1991.662604
(258.0,10.0):1850.995862
(172.0,11.0):1301.179960
(174.0,11.0):1436.984094
(176.0,11.0):1695.954099
(179.0,11.0):1548.015013
(228.0,11.0):4640.928585
(242.0,11.0):169.617203
(251.0,11.0):784.921333
(253.0,11.0):983.118859
(255.0,11.0):1181.474433
(256.0,11.0):1303.398235
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep=":")
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution if strings in column `ji` - [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) column for extracting, [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'ji']))
<class 'str'>

df[['a','b']] = df.pop('ji').str.strip('()').str.split(', ', expand=True).astype(float)
```

Or use `list comprehension` if no missing values and performance is important:

```
L = [x.strip('()').split(', ') for x in df.pop('ji')]
df[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).astype(float)

print (df)
         length      a     b
0   3283.458479   75.0   5.0
1   1431.312901   96.0   5.0
2   1364.592959   97.0   5.0
3   3736.322308  247.0   5.0
4   2655.910005   81.0   7.0
5   1752.293687   93.0   7.0
6    427.844417  242.0   7.0
7   3725.823013  248.0   7.0
```

If tuples then create nested list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'ji']))
<class 'tuple'>

df[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('ji').values.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks! The first example provides the following error:
File "dist_test.py", line 43
    <class 'str'>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


The second example provides the results I need but also shows an error as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
0    75.0   5.0
  File "dist_test.py", line 47, in <module>
1    96.0   5.0
    L = [x.strip('()').split(', ') for x in ar2.pop('ji')]
2    97.0   5.0
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

And the third example:

 File "dist_test.py", line 53
    <class 'tuple'>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @GTreg first check `print (type(df.loc[0, 'ji']))` and if `<class 'str'>` then use first solution and if `<class 'tuple'>` then use second one. Also `<class 'tuple'>` and `<class 'str'>` is nevessary remove from code, it is only output.

Comment: thanks again - sadly this doesn't work as I am given the following error `L = [x.strip('()').split(', ') for x in ar2.pop('ji')]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: I have edited the original question  as I found a work around. Thanks again!

Comment: @GTreg So `df[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('ji').values.tolist(), index=df. index)` not working?

Comment: out of interest @jezrael - how did you convert the column of tuples (as strings) in this example to tuples?

Comment: My approach was: 
```python
[
    tuple(k[1].to_list())
    for k in df["ji"]
    .transform(lambda x: re.sub(r"\(|\)", "", x))
    .str.split(",", expand=True)
    .iterrows()
]
```
I feel like there's a (much!) nicer approach, but I'm not too sure what it would be

Answer (score 2):

edit:

If `'ji'` contains tuples, it's much simpler:

```
df[['j', 'i']] = df.pop('ji').apply(pd.Series)
```

---

Given

```
>>> df                                                                            
            ji       length
0   (75.0,5.0)  3283.458479
1   (96.0,5.0)  1431.312901
2   (97.0,5.0)  1364.592959
3  (247.0,5.0)  3736.322308
4   (81.0,7.0)  2655.910005
>>>
>>> df.dtypes                                                                     
ji         object
length    float64
dtype: object
```

i.e. when the `'ji'` column contains strings, I'd make use of `ast.literal_eval` here.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> def split_to_df(string): 
...:    return pd.Series(literal_eval(string)) 
>>>
>>> df[['val1', 'val2']] = df.pop('ji').apply(split_to_df)                                                                                                      
>>> df                                                                                                                                                   
        length   val1  val2
0  3283.458479   75.0   5.0
1  1431.312901   96.0   5.0
2  1364.592959   97.0   5.0
3  3736.322308  247.0   5.0
4  2655.910005   81.0   7.0
```

(Usage of `pop` inspired by jezrael's answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I sadly get the following error: "ValueError: malformed string"

Comment: @GTreg It works for the dataframe as shown. Can you give us code in your question to instantiate the dataframe such that we are talking about exactly the same data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df['a'] = df['ji'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['b'] = df['ji'].apply(lambda x: x[1])

df.drop(['ji'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks - but I said that I don't want to use lambda ;)